# Hoffman broamide degradation but with alkoxide as base instead of NaOH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amines

> [image]
>
> Ans.3

I thought it would be similar to Hoffman bromide reaction, and hence the answer (1) but turns out the answer is (3), suggesting the alkoxide attacks the formed amine. But, I couldn't find any references for the reaction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is wrong, the answer should be the carbamate 4.
The reaction intermediate is the isocyanate which is captured by MeOH to give the carbamate (std Hofmann mechanism below from masterorganicchemistry.com). For a Hofmann in MeOH see this Org Syn procedure [here](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=V78P0234)

[image]